# Refreshing html control through code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a html control on my aspx page

```
<td>
  <input type="text" id="txtSubCode1" name="txtSubCode1" value="<%# this._SubCodeHeader1 %>" />
</td>
```

In my code behind I have the property

```
protected string _SubCodeHeader1 { get; set; }
```

Is it possible to refresh the html control when a new value is assigned to _SubCodeHeader1? Basically my html control never displays the value assigned to _SubCodeHeader1. I want to set the value of html control from code behind without using runat

Comment: No I need this as html control as I am using it it javascript from other aspx pages. I want to set the value of html control from code behind without using runat

Comment: @inquisitive_mind No, you do not need `runat="server"` in this scenario. He's not trying to access the control, he's trying to set the value of the control, which just requires a bit of inline syntax.

Comment: Are you getting an exception with your current code? At what point do you assign a value to `_SubCodeHeader1`? You need to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: No I don't get any exception. I have other controls on my page (its huge). On click of another control I am trying to get this property _SubCodeHeader1. In the debugger I can see the property is set but on the page I don't see it refreshed

Comment: Did you read the link I provided? Please follow the directions there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call ***DataBind*** on every postback. *For example -*

```
<input type="text" id="txtSubCode1" name="txtSubCode1" 
    value="<%# this._SubCodeHeader1 %>" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

### Code Behind

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected string _SubCodeHeader1 { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            _SubCodeHeader1 = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _SubCodeHeader1 = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change `<%# this._SubCodeHeader1 %>` to `<%= this._SubCodeHeader1 %>` 
if you want to set value without doing anything extra.

This statement `<%#` runs  only when called a controls `DataBind()` method is called, or a parents control's `DataBind()` method.

Comment: I tried using Databind() in the property setter but does not work. <%= gives an error "System.Web.HttpException: The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)."